# Quiero generar un queryset que me devuelva la cantidad de usuarios por categoría

Tags: python-3.x, django, sql, django-models, djangorestframework

soy bastante nuevo usando django actualmente necesito obtener un query que me permita identificar por categoría cuantos usuarios existen, ejemplo: imaginemos que tenemos la siguientes categorias:
Docente     Profesores
No Docente  Técnicos educativos
No Docente  Enfermera
No Docente  Administrativo
No Docente  Fisioterapeuta
No Docente  Integrador Social

lo que necesito es utilizando un queryset ,determinar cuantos usarios son , Profesores, Fisio, etc, etc.

Aqui os dejo los modelos:

```
class User ( AbstractUser ) :  # Extendind the User django model
    id = models.UUIDField ( primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False )
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField ( 'email address', unique=True )
    observation = models.CharField ( max_length=230, null=True, blank=True )
    is_account = models.BooleanField ( default=False )
    is_signup = models.BooleanField ( default=False )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField ( auto_now_add=True, null=True )
    center = models.ForeignKey ( Center, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    #category = models.OneToOneField ( CenterUserCategory, null=True,  default=None,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = CustomUserManager ()

    class Meta :
        db_table = 'auth_user'

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.first_name

class CenterUserCategory ( models.Model ) :
    USER_TYPE = (
        ('D', 'Docente'),
        ('N', 'No docente'),
        ('O', 'Otro'),
    )

    id = models.UUIDField ( primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False )
    category = models.CharField ( max_length=1, choices=USER_TYPE, verbose_name='Categoria de Usuario' )
    description = models.CharField ( max_length=230, null=True, blank=False )
    center = models.ForeignKey ( Center, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    groupmembers = models.ManyToManyField ( User, through='CategoryMembers' )
    status = models.BooleanField ( default=True )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField ( auto_now_add=True, null=True )

    objects = AllManagers ()

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.description
        # return "Centro:  "+ (self.center.name)+" / "+(self.description)

class CategoryMembers ( models.Model ) :
    id = models.UUIDField ( primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False )
    centercategory = models.ForeignKey ( CenterUserCategory, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    user = models.ForeignKey ( User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    status = models.BooleanField(null=False,blank=True, default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField ( auto_now_add=True, null=True )
```

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas serán ignoradas o en determinado momento borradas ya que debes de poner el código donde tu lo hayas intentado no solo copiar y pegar la tarea, este foro es de ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias maneras de lograrlo, por ejemplo, lo puedes hacer con [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
>>> from django.db.models import Count
>>> x = CenterUserCategory.objects.annotate(Count('groupmembers'))
>>> x
<QuerySet [<CenterUserCategory: CenterUserCategory object (1)>, <CenterUserCategory: CenterUserCategory object (2)>, <CenterUserCategory: CenterUserCategory object (3)>]>
>>> x[1].groupmembers__count
3
>>> x[2].groupmembers__count
3
>>> x[0].groupmembers__count
0
```

Cada instancia del modelo `CenterUserCategory` o cada categoría tendrá un atributo llamado `groupmembers__count`, que es el numero de usuarios que pertenecen a dicha categoria.

También, puedes controlar el nombre del atributo u anotación:

```
>>> x = CenterUserCategory.objects.annotate(numero_de_usuarios = Count('groupmembers'))
>>> x[1].numero_de_usuarios
3
```

---

Otra forma, seria así:

```
>>> x = CenterUserCategory.objects.filter(category='O')[0]
>>> x.groupmembers.count()
3
```

Cualquiera es valida. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: @Juio Cesar, muchísimas gracias, de lujo funciona

Answer (score 0):

Yo me había realizado lo siguiente:

```
centeruserscategories = mycenter.centerusercategory_set.all ().exclude ( description__contains='--CUENTA--' )
```

luego me hice una función llamada: CountCategoryMember

```
CountCategoryMember(pk):
    mycategory = CenterUserCategory.objects.get ( pk=pk )
    return (mycategory.groupmembers.count ())
```

y el un ciclo for la llamaba e imprimia uno a uno:

```
for centerusercategory in  centeruserscategories:
    print (str(CountCategoryMember(centerusercategory.pk)) '|'+centerusercategory.description, style='List Bullet' )
```