# Obtener un resultado dentro de un queryset bajo la relacion de Mucho a Muchos Django

Tags: python, django, sql, django-forms

He tenido problemas para poder hacer que un QuerySet me devuelva lo que necesito. Anteriormente hice [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/398715/quiero-generar-un-queryset-que-me-devuelva-la-cantidad-de-usuarios-por-categor%c3%ada), alli estan lo modelos con los cuales estoy trabajando.

Ahora con estos modelos quisiera obtener un resultado de un QuerySet que me traiga una lista de: `user.pk`, `user.firstname` y `centerUserCategory`

A ver si es posible. Un saludo

Comment: Viendo los modelos de la pregunta que adjuntas, el modelo `User` **no tiene ningún tipo de relación con el modelo `centerUserCategory`**, pero veo una relación `OneToOneField` a dicho modelo, **pero dicha linea esta comentada** (`#`), ¿actualmente sigue comentada o no?... por favor edita tu pregunta y adjunta tus modelos **actuales**.

Answer (score 0):

Hola  a todos luego de intentar varias cosas, gracias a Julio, me di cuenta que también debía agregar una relación uno a muchos con center dentro de mi modelo CategoryMember, de   esta manera también tengo mas control con respecto a todos los modelos que pertenecen a un centro.
Posteriormente leyendo un poco me di cuenta que existe la sentencia select_related de que básicamente es como un inner join.

```
users=CategoryMember.objects.select_related('user').filter(center_id=center.pk)
```

para ver el query: uso :

```
print(str(users.query))
```

y par imprimir los datos:

```
{% for user in users %}
     {{ user.user.pk}} ,  user.user.first_name}, user.centercategory
     # ...
{% endfor %}
```

Espero le sirva a otra persona.